# fsck tool for UDF filesysyem in 14.04

Tags: fsck, udf

Is there a tool to make `fsck` check an UDF file system on portable hard drive? I have the `udftools` package installed but there is no tool to check the UDF filesystem in it.

Answer (score 0):

Some `udftools` will have a `udffsck`. That would be the better approach but the upstream project is [dead](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/udftools/+bug/384156) so unlikely Ubuntu will ever have it.

You can try fsck for "udfs" like this...

```
sudo su
fsck -F udfs /dev/{device} {device-name}
```

- From `man fsck`: " fs-specific-options. Options which are not understood by fsck are passed to the filesystem-specific checker.  These arguments must not take arguments, as there is no way for fsck to be  able  to  properly  guess  which  arguments  take options and which don't." If it works
- {device} and {device-name} should be changed to the device and name used for your portable hard drive
- you probably will need to do this on a root prompt so `sudo su` 1st. Be careful when using the # prompt.

Otherwise you will not be able to do this...

Comment: Thanks i see the bug, udffsck is missing. fsck -F udfs /dev/sdf1 exit 2 because called missing fsck.udf.  I have formatted my external usb hdd with UDF format and its 3 times outperforms in writes the same drive using ntfs-3g (27mb/c against 12mb/c).

Comment: Ok. I am sorry Ubuntu let you down on this ;)

Comment: I have download udftool from SF udffsck do nothing {return 0}

Comment: Could there be plans afoot to breathe [life](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/udftools/+bug/384156/comments/3) into the dream of fsck tool for UDF, using code from Solaris?

Comment: Are you sure that this works? I need some examples showing that it works. I don't believe that fsck has an utility for udf format. Do you? See this: https://github.com/pali/udftools/issues/21 and https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=775962;msg=5

Comment: It used to. It was a patch from oracle as an attempt for fsck_udfs. The 1st link you posted is currently the best tool.